# Set state twice in onChange ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange

I have the following snippet of React that I can't get to work right.  Essentially I'm displaying a spinner based on the state of this onChange call (due to the update sometimes taking 3-5 seconds).  However, the first call to set state seems to go unnoticed (or as I'm researching being batched up) and therefore the state of loading is never updated.  This is part of a toggle/switch a user can select infinite times on a page (if they desired obviously).

```
  const [state, setState] = useState({ loading: false });  
  const onToggleChange = () => {
    setState(prevState => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        loading: true,
      };
    });
    console.log("loading1: " + JSON.stringify(state));

    // this takes a long time depending on the users actions
    setFilterMode(!filterChecked);

    setState(prevState => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        loading: false,
      };
    });
    console.log("loading2: " + JSON.stringify(state));
  };
```

I've reviewed the current questions/answer (which is how I got as far as the above), but it still doesn't load correctly.

Comment: Is this your actual code? If you're running this code on page load, it'd be best to put it in a useEffect with an empty depdency array (so it only loads once). You can initialize `loading` to true at first so it displays the loading screen, and in whatever logic happens after your page loads, you set loading to false. You don't need to nest it in an object if it's the only state var as well. (e.g. `const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)`

Comment: I nested it to match with the prevState design I was finding, I had a simple boolean before.  `useEffect` isn't working either as it never updated the state of loading.

Comment: In a functional component, every line in the body is called on every single render (since it's a function). You can't have state setting calls in the body of a functional component.